# Count turtles in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to make one button in Netlogo with the below code but the problem that count shows me in the observer 0 while it should be 10, any idea why?

```
    breed [ planets planet ] 

planets-own [ distance-to-earth diameter heading ] 


to create_planets
 ca 
  ask n-of 10 patches [ sprout 1 ]
  show count planets
end
```

Comment: Whoever voted to close this and down-voted, please don't try to close NetLogo questions if you don't know the language. This is a perfectly good question, the OP has stated that `count planets` returned 0 instead of the expected 10, and the code presented is the correct code to present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told the patches to `sprout` but not that you wanted planets to be the breed of turtles that sprouted. This will create generic turtles. Try `sprout-planets` instead.